# getElementById.value on input type returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to alert the value of an input type. The alert gives me 'undefined'.

I've tried looking through some other posts but without any luck.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <script>

            /* Global Vars */
            var firstNumber = document.getElementById('firstNumber').value;
            var secondNumber = document.getElementById('secondNumber').value;
            var plus = document.getElementById('plus');
            var minus = document.getElementById('minus');
            var times = document.getElementById('times');
            var divide = document.getElementById('divide');
            var result = document.getElementById('result');

            function cool() {
                //var sum = Number(firstNumber) + Number(secondNumber);

                alert(secondNumber);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Getal 1" id="firstNumber" /> <input type="number" placeholder="Getal 2" id="secondNumber" /><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="result" disabled /><br><br>
        <button id="plus">+</button> <button id="minus">-</button> <button id="times">x</button> <button id="divide">/</button>

        <button onClick="cool()">Test</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move your script block below the html elements

Comment: @karthikr It doesn't alert anything now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look in the web console, you'll find an error there: `TypeError: Cannot read property value of null`"

This is because your code is doing this:

```
var firstNumber = document.getElementById('firstNumber').value;
```

**before** the element exists, which means `document.getElementById('firstNumber')` gives you `null`, and looking up `value` on `null` throws an error (preventing all the rest of that step-by-step code from running, but not preventing the `cool` function from being created, as that's done first, before any step-by-step code was run). That error prevents `secondNumber` ever getting a value, and so it keeps its default `undefined` value which you can see later when you call `cool`.

In general, unless you have a specific reason not to, put your scripts just before the closing `</body>` tag. In particular, this business of putting scripts in the `head` is an anti-pattern. So *(but there's more to do, keep reading)*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Getal 1" id="firstNumber" /> <input type="number" placeholder="Getal 2" id="secondNumber" /><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="result" disabled /><br><br>
        <button id="plus">+</button> <button id="minus">-</button> <button id="times">x</button> <button id="divide">/</button>

        <button onClick="cool()">Test</button>
        <script>

            /* Global Vars */
            var firstNumber = document.getElementById('firstNumber').value;
            var secondNumber = document.getElementById('secondNumber').value;
            var plus = document.getElementById('plus');
            var minus = document.getElementById('minus');
            var times = document.getElementById('times');
            var divide = document.getElementById('divide');
            var result = document.getElementById('result');

            function cool() {
                //var sum = Number(firstNumber) + Number(secondNumber);

                alert(secondNumber);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**But**: Your code is reading the values of the inputs as of when the page is loaded (code outside of functions is run right away). You probably mean to read them when the button is clicked. If so, move your code reading them *into* the `cool` function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Getal 1" id="firstNumber" /> <input type="number" placeholder="Getal 2" id="secondNumber" /><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="result" disabled /><br><br>
        <button id="plus">+</button> <button id="minus">-</button> <button id="times">x</button> <button id="divide">/</button>

        <button onClick="cool()">Test</button>
        <script>

        function cool() {
            var firstNumber = document.getElementById('firstNumber').value;
            var secondNumber = document.getElementById('secondNumber').value;
            var plus = document.getElementById('plus');
            var minus = document.getElementById('minus');
            var times = document.getElementById('times');
            var divide = document.getElementById('divide');
            var result = document.getElementById('result');

                //var sum = Number(firstNumber) + Number(secondNumber);

            alert(secondNumber);
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that your variables are no longer global variables, now that they're nicely *inside* a function. In general, avoid global variables, the global namespace is already **far** too crowded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, when I try this it won't alert anything.

Comment: Also, shouldnt `var secondNumber = document.getElementById('secondNumber').value;` be moved inside `cool()` so it gets the *fresh* value when the function is called?

Comment: That's a *different* problem: You're reading the values of the inputs as they are when the page is loaded. If you want to read them as of when the button is clicked, move your code reading their values *into* `cool`.